# Removing redirection operator does not change output. Why?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, io-redirection, io

I saw this usage of redirection somewhere, and thought it was a typo:

```bash
grep root < /etc/passwd
```

But after I run it, I saw that it gives the same output with
`grep root /etc/passwd`:

```bash
$ grep root < /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

$ grep root   /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

The same thing happens with

```bash
cat < /etc/passwd
cat   /etc/passwd
```

However, redirection is ignored when used with `ls`:

```bash
ls < /etc/passwd
```

does not print the same output with

```bash
ls  /etc/passwd
```

What is happening?

Comment: If the command _requires_ standard input, you _must_ use redirection. If the command _requires_ file name parameter, you _must not_ use redirection. If the command _accepts_ both file name parameter and standard input, you _may_ use redirection, but is preferable to let the command handle the file operation.

Comment: Trying another explanation: `ls < /etc/passwd` not works for the same reason why neither `cat /etc/passwd | ls` works. If you run `grep ''` or `cat` from the command prompt (no input, no parameters), they will wait for you to enter the input from the keyboard. But `ls` will not do that as it expects no input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many utilities which work with files will accept *stdin* (standard input) as streamed input, or accept the file-name as a parameter..  Your `< file` examples are redirecting the output of the file to the utility. The file was opened by the shell and passed on to your utility via *stdin* ..

On the other hand, with  `cat file`, *cat* is handling the opening and reading of *file*, and no redirection is involved.

`ls` never reads a file, therefore it does not take a file name as a parameter with a view to *opening and reading* the file.. (it accepts file-name masks) ... For `ls`, the redirection action is, in effect, ignored because nothing in the process reads the shell-opened file...

To determine how any utility behaves, just type `man utility-name` in the terminal...  *man* is a contraction of *manual* ... eg. `man cat` presents you with *cat's manual*

Comment: I always think `wc` is a useful program to serve as a demonstration, because it behaves slightly differently with a file to a redirection: in the former case the filename is printed.  With a redirection you can capture the output in a subshell and use it as an integer.